# Project Euler 2: The right answer, but something bothering me in the code

Tags: python, loops

```
# Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
# 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
# By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

fibon = [1, 2] # The first 2 numbers in the sequence
addtoend = 0 # The number that will be added to the end of the sequence
evens = [] # Will hold the even numbers in the sequence

while fibon[-1] <= 4000000: # Starts the While loop
    addtoend = fibon[-1] + fibon[-2] # Sets addtoend equal to the last two items in fibon[]
    fibon.append(addtoend) # Appends addtoend onto the end of fibon[]

print fibon # Print out fibon[]

for i in fibon: # Starts the for loop
    if i % 2 == 0: # If the remainder of the current item in the list when divided by 2 is 0...
        evens.append(i) # Then add it to the evens[] list
    else: # Otherwise...
        pass # Just skip it

print evens # Print the evens array, with all the even numbers from fibon[] inside it.
print sum(evens) # Print the sum of all the even numbers from evens[]
```

This gives the result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887]
[2, 8, 34, 144, 610, 2584, 10946, 46368, 196418, 832040, 3524578]
4613732
```

I checked the answer on project Euler, and it was correct, which is good :D But one thing I'm not sure about, is when it prints out the list of numbers in the sequence, it has the number: **5702887** on the end. This is over the 4 million of the loop, and while it doesn't affect the overall answer, I'm confused as to how it's there.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Because you're appending a new value **after** checking that the current last value is <= 4000000.

Comment: Note that you don't need to store all 4e6 values just to find the sum of them.

Comment: @thg435 It's not four million values, it's the  values not exceeding four million. If you start with `F(0) = 0`, that's 34 values.

Comment: Note that if the first value larger than the limit was even, your code would incorrectly add that value. Good that you wondered.

Comment: @DanielFischer: indeed. Still, the statement holds - there's no need to store them.

Comment: @thg435 True. You don't even need to compute them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this piece of code

```
while fibon[-1] <= 4000000:
    addtoend = fibon[-1] + fibon[-2] 
    fibon.append(addtoend)
```

Now consider the case when `fibon[-1]` contains 3524578. Since the condition is `true`, the loop will run, and add and append the next digit in the sequence, which is 5702887.

Now the condition becomes `false` and the loop ends.

**EDIT:** To avoid it, you can do something like this.

```
while True:
    addtoend = fibon[-1] + fibon[-2]
    if addtoend > 4000000: break
    fibon.append(addtoend)
```

Comment: Ah, I thought it would be the loop going one step too far. Thanks, is there any simple way to alter my code so that this won't happen?

Comment: Please see my edit. There are other ways to do it as well. :)

Comment: Thanks, simple and easy to add :D